# Finding out key for minimum value of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
scores = {5: 35044.51299744237, 25: 29016.41319191076, 50: 27405.930473214907, 100: 27282.50803885739, 250: 27893.822225701646, 500: 29454.18598068598}
```

Scores is a dict I have defined and now I want to find out the key, for the minimum value in the dictionary, which should return me 100.

I notice that it can be done like this

```
min(scores, key=scores.get)
```

But I don't really understand what the above line means. I am new to python programming. Can anyone break this line down for me visually? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What don't you understand? Explain your current attempt to parse the code, and perhaps we could help fill in the rest.

Comment: [Here's a section about key functions from the Sorting How To article](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).  `min` works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) provided by Patrick

> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes.

So basically using `scores.get` as the key function calls `scores.get(key)` for each key in scores.

When passing scores as the data to min it treats it basically as a list of the keys so essentially it’s finding the minimum value and returning you the associated key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more simply:  When you call `min(scores)`, you are returning the item in `scores` that has the lowest value among all items in `scores`.

When you call `min(scores, key=some_func)`, you are returning the item in `scores` that has the lowest value of `some_func(item)`, instead.

For example, if `scores` is a list of (unique) integers, then `min(scores)` will return the lowest integer.  If `some_func(x)` returns the negative of `x`, then `min(scores, key=some_func)` will return the maximum, instead.